# Can I put down "I'm wondering about whether....."

Tags: prepositions

I'm learning about indirect questions, but I'm confused with the use of "wondering about".

> I was wondering about one thing. Can Lisa fly a helicopter?（combine the sentences）

The answer is "*I was wondering whether/if  Lisa can fly a helicopter (or not).*"

Can I put down "*I was wondering **about** whether/if  Lisa can fly a helicopter.*"

It seems grammatically correct, but is it common for a native speaker to say so?

Comment: The "about" in your substitute version just feels redundant and awkward to me.

Comment: The entirety of the first sentence *(I was wondering about one thing)* is just a ***discourse marker***. It doesn't mean anything, and it makes no difference exactly how it's phrased. Incidentally, though, native Anglophones don't use the continuous here anywhere near as often as learners. We're just as likely to start with ***I wonder if...*** or ***I wondered if...*** if we're going to "beat around the bush" a bit. Or we just ask directly: *Can Lisa fly a helicopter?*

Comment: As Italian English Learners, I can confirm we would tend to use *I was wondering* instead of *I wondered* because in Italian *Mi stavo domandando* (*I was wondering*) is the phrase used in such cases.

Comment: @user888379 - 'About' _is_ redundant. We wonder _about_ a thing or situation, but we wonder _whether_  a fact is true or not.

Comment: Both "whether" and "if" are possible when they function as direct complement of "wondering", but when the interrogative clause is complement of a preposition like "about", only "whether" is possible. Thus *"I was wondering about if Lisa can fly a helicopter" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Note that "I was wondering about whether Lisa can fly a helicopter" means "I was wondering about the answer to the question 'Can Lisa fly a helicopter?'"

Answer (score 0):

> *I was wondering about whether/if Lisa can fly a helicopter.

I add to the comments.

[VOA](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/do-you-know-what-an-indirect-question-is/4439120.html) explains the use of *I was wondering* and gives an example:

> Can you please help me move on Saturday?

> I was wondering **if** you could help me move on Saturday.

Applying the step to

> Can Lisa fly a helicopter.

with the **discourse marker** (thanks to @FumbleFingers for the term) first sentence,

we get the answer you mentioned.  We should not include *about*. **I wondered** would be better than *I was wondering* unless the sentence continues with something like "when she surprised me ..."

Comment: When the interrogative clause begins with "whether", it is fine to use "about", though it is optional. But when the interrogative clause begins with "if", then "about" is disallowed.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *I was wondering about whether* / *if Lisa can fly a helicopter.*

Both "whether" and "if" are possible when the interrogative functions as direct complement of "wondering".

But when the interrogative clause is complement of a preposition like "about", only "whether" is possible.